# Validating model and overwriting values (if necessary) in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: angular, validation, model, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC web application which uses Angular 9 for the frontend and a SQL Server database. The website contains quite a few "create" (or "update") dialogs where the user can create different types of objects which will then be written to the database.

In most cases, there is some validation logic involved when such objects are created. For example, some attribute values of these objects need to be in a certain range like between 0 and 100 (depending on the type of the attribute).
For some attributes, there are also default values defined which should be used if the user does not enter any other value for the attribute.

Currently, such validations are done in the frontend via Angular FormControls which obviously means that the validations can be bypassed easily by directly sending POST/PUT requests to the server instead of using the frontend.

Is there any way to apply such validations in the frontend and also in the backend without implementing them in the frontend and backend separately?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to apply such validations in the frontend and also in the backend without implementing them in the frontend and backend separately?

In your Angular front-end with MVC/API back-end, you can not implement/customize data validator and make it perform both client-side validation and server-side validation in one place.

As we know, user input validation take place on the client side, which could help **avoid an unnecessary round trip to the server** when there are input errors on a form.

As you mentioned, some malicious users may bypass client side script, so normally we also perform server-side validation to protect against the malicious inputs. In ASP.NET Core, model validation feature help validate model data, and we can check `ModelState.IsValid` then react appropriately in code logic.

Besides, you can know the concept and basic usage of model validation in ASP.NET Core, from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1